# Web interface with python backend

Tags: python, cgi

I developed a simple application in Python (with a Tkinter interface). But now I want provide a web interface for the same. I know that the python script will wun on the server as CGI. But I would like everything to happen on one page i.e. something like this:

1. There is a text box for the user to provide input
2. When a submit button is clicked, the python script runs on the input and generates the output
3. The output is displayed on the same page without the page reloading

I think Ajax can be used to do this (and I'll learn it if that's the only way), but is there any easier way to do this? I tried generating the front end in python, and linking the button to a function in the same script but that doesn't work...

Thanks

PS: Sorry if the title and the tags are a bit misleadsing...i wasn't so sure what to pick...

EDIT: I tried this but it doesn't work

```
#!/usr/bin/python2
import cgi

print 'Content-type: text/html'
print """
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
"""

data = cgi.FieldStorage()
sometext = data['sometext'].value
if sometext != '':
    print "<p>" + sometext + "</p>"

print """
        <form action="test.py" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="sometext">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
"""
```

Comment: To update a page without reloading you will need AJAX so JS. With the front end in Python I'm not sure what you mean there

Comment: Maybe the easiest way to do this is to rewrite the (simple) application in JavaScript (possibly using JQueryUI or some-such) as part of the static web page.

Comment: You really don't want to being using bare CGI in 2013. You *can* write the frontend in python if you use the pyjamas package, although doing it in javascript directly is almost certainly going to be easier.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that the above code needed to use getvalue function.
This worked when I saved the work as test.cgi and ran from my public_html (my directory that hosts all my html for web view).

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import cgi

print( 'Content-type: text/html')
print( """
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
""")

data = cgi.FieldStorage()
sometext = data.getvalue('sometext',  '')
if sometext != '':
    print( "<p>" + sometext + "</p>")

print( """
        <form action="test.cgi" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="sometext">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
""")
```